# SQLite in Windows Phone Runtime Component

Tags: c++, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013

I want to use native C++ code within my WindowsPhone 8 Application. For this purpose I did build a "Windows Phone Runtime Component" to wrap my C++ code. I simply compile my native code with Visual Studio when I compile the Runtime Component. This took some tweaking but Visual Studio is now compiling.

Now my native code needs SQLite. For other platforms I was able to just compile sqlite3 with my native code and got it to run. But I just can't get it to work with Visual Studio. My native class looks like this:

```
#include "Main.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

//visual studio needs additional imports for std
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#endif


void NativeClass::testDataBase() {
    //some SQL stuff here
}
```

What I have tried:

1. My first idea was to try to solve this like I did for iOS and Android. I tried to include the sqlite header and .c files. I also tried all options and compiler flags listened [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=HowToCompileWithVsNet). When I do this with a Win32 project it compiles just fine. But when I try to compile it for my Runtime component I get a lots of errors belonging to lines like this:

   ```
   { "AreFileApisANSI",         (SYSCALL)AreFileApisANSI,         0 },
   ```

   And the Error is:

   ```
   Error 2 error C2065: 'AreFileApisANSI': undeclared identifier
   ```
2. The next idea was to just import the headers and link the binaries. With all a lot of different errors and problems this keeps failing. Usually going back to the problem, that I'm not able to compile or find a working and for arm compiled lib.

EDIT: 3.
Something else I tried and forgot to mention. I tried using the SQLite packages within NuGet manager. But I can't use the sqlite-net-wp8 package. I get an error explaining that I have defined "Native:0.0v" or something similar. This error is unfortunately not to helpful to me.

I'm asking for ways to solve this here. This could be a solution on how to get one of my approaches to work. Or it could be a completely different way to solve this.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013. And I have Windows running in Parallels on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C compile flags for Windows Phone 8 are different than for general Windows.

In particular SQLITE needs to be compiled not to use APIs which are not available on WP8. 
I find that the following works (v3.7.17 of SQLITE):

`/DSQLITE_OS_WINRT=1 /DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 /DSQLITE_WIN32_FILEMAPPING_API=1`

This seems to match [what others have found](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/81598) on the SQLite mailing list.

Comment: I have tried it and I get another Error (this time it is an linker issue) "sqlite3.lo : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_key_v2 referenced
 in function sqlite3Pragma"

Comment: Hi I just tried it with visual studio. The previous errors are gone. But I have a new one.    Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: void __cdecl std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >::_Compat(class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > > const &)const " (?_Compat@?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@QBAXABV12@@Z) any ideas?

Comment: Sry for so many comments. My error above seems to be a debug related issue with a release configuration it is just compiling fine with visual studio. Much thanks for your help!